# If a root $ \xi $ of the polynomial f(x) is adjoined to $ \mathbb{Z}_{5} $

Tags: extension-field

(a) Show that the polynomial $ f(x)=x^{3}+x+1 $ is irreducible over $ \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x] $ . (b) If  a root $ \xi $ of the polynomial f(x) is adjoined to 
$ \mathbb{Z}_{5} $ , how many elements are there in the resulting field $ \mathbb{Z}_{5}(\xi) $. $$ $$ I got 125 elements. Is it true ?

Comment: Yes, it is true: $\mathbf Z_5(\xi)$ is a $\mathbf Z_5$-vector space of dimension $3$.

Comment: Because $f$ is irreducible $\mathbb{Z}_5(\xi) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/(f(x))$